# Sticky Expandable Header(parent) with a Recyclerview item(child)

Tags: android

Im trying to implement a Sticky header like the one in Instagram, combined with an expandable RecyclerView. I have used the [Expandable-Recycler-View library](https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view) and succeed to achieve headers with expandable lists. Is there a way to make the header sticky as I scroll down?

Comment: Maybe something like this could work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24862951/3114383

I am gonna try to implement the same behaviour like you want.. if i manage something, i will let you know

Comment: This one might help you aswell: https://github.com/TonicArtos/SuperSLiM

Comment: I gave the superSlim library a quick try, but didn't work out for me. The tutorial is not well written as well

Comment: well its probably not going to work in a quick try.. You are going to have to have to study the example code and apply it as needed.

Comment: Yea I know. I will come back to it and give it a good try after I'm done with my other tasks

Comment: @RedEagle Any updates? Did you get it working?

Comment: @RedEagle Have to found any solution for this?